# Passing class instance as a pointer and using the overloaded subscript operator on this pointer

Tags: c++

I have a class that holds an array of integers and to get a reference of this array the subscript operator [] is overloaded (this is a stripped down example with logic checks etc removed):

```
class Foo {
public:

Foo() {};

// and overload the [] operator
int& operator[](const int index);

private:
const int LEN = 7;
int arr[LEN];
};

int& Foo::operator[](const int index) {
    return arr[index];
}
```

A pointer of an instance of such class (named boo) is passed to a function. Now what I want to do is:

```
int val = boo[0];
```

but it fails "error: invalid cast from type ‘Foo’ to type ‘int’".

My first idea was that Im passing a pointer to a class and I should bring a copy of the instance into scope and use that copy instead. This works. But Im curious if it would be possible to use the user defined type as a true built in type? Should I use a wrapper?

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts ([this one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1285674/siim-veskilt) and [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1909671/siim-veskilt)), which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the overloaded operator is defined for objects, not pointers to objects. There's two options:

```
int val = boo->operator[](0);
```

or

```
int val = (*boo)[0];
```

Or you can pass the object (by value or reference) instead of a pointer to it.

Your case is equivalent to:

```
Boo* b = ....;
b[0];           //this returns a Boo object
```

as opposed to:

```
Boo b;
b[0];           //calls operator[]
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to either use :

```
boo->operator[] ( 0 );
```

or

```
(*boo)[0];
```

I.E. dereference the pointer to the object boo.